# Why is an operating system software loaded from hard disk than from a rom chip?

Tags: operating-system, rom

> Why is an operating system software
>   loaded from hard disk than from a rom
>   chip?

I was asked this question and I am unable to find the answer.

Can someone explain?

Comment: 1980s home micros (BBC, Spectrum, Commodore etc) had ROM-based operating systems; a few years later the Macintosh ran from a 64k ROM, and Acorn had a 4-megabyte ROM for RISC OS. But updates were awkward, and that became a big deal as users wanted more OS features more quickly, plus a larger OS tends to mean a higher bug-fix rate as there's more code to go wrong. Plus machines went online, so security exploits became more common (yes the ROM's being read-only offers some protection, but crashing the current session or reading private data is bad enough already even if you can't corrupt the OS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest answer is ease of patching and extensibility.  ROM cannot easily be patched - though with some permanent storage location and some creativity and foresight when building your initial ROM, you can patch it with some hook code.

Size of ROM isn't a great answer.  CD/DVDs are a permanent location and could be used, though not ROM 'chips'.  ROM chips can be made large enough to handle an OS (heck some versions of Linux fit on floppies not too long ago) and wouldn't be that expensive, though worse than a DVD for distribution costs.

Replacing an OS via a new ROM chip isn't that attractive, but if you just plugged in a new PCI card, would that be so bad?  We do that already so this isn't a great argument either.

Access speed to a ROM chip, generally, will be much superior than to a harddrive so you would get a performance boost this way, so that's actually a plus.  Also having a ROM makes it that much harder for malware to infect the OS - another plus.

So, in general, I see many pluses for a ROM based OS vs a RAM based one.  Nice question.

Comment: Nice information and comparison. Thanks

Comment: I looked up "why aren't OS stored in ROM?" out of curiosity to get here. And I must say, why doesn't somebody design a program that runs during boot that takes the existing OS and separates it into a ROM partition? It would have much of the benefits outlined here and it would be more efficient than having a windows folder showing up in C:. You could also make a new OS without replacing a chip; just delete the partition and make a new one. I think this could also benefit dual booting.

Answer (score 2):

An OS on a harddisk can be **replaced** by installing a new one onto that disk, and it can be easily updated.

If your OS is burnt into a ROM, that won't really work. Replace the OS?? Rip out the ROM chip and stick in a new one.... not a very attractive suggestion! (at least not for a desktop PC or notebook)

Comment: "easily updated" should not be the litmus test.  The OS has so many moving parts, why don't we have computer mechanics that oversee maintenance of our computers?  An OS update should be  something that only comes through the proper channels and it should be authenticated/validated by a certified/licensed third party who knows what's necessary to keep a computer running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess iOS/Android is not loaded from a hard disk, so that depends.

Answer (score 0):

Size and demand. Flash chips large enough to hold an OS that most people want/would want to run are ridiculously expensive.

Comment: ROM is not the same as a 'flash chip'

Comment: @Kirk: Most modern computers do not use ROM anymore. They use Flash to store the BIOS.

Comment: I disagree that the parts of the OS that need to be immutable between updates are that big.  The Kernel, Drivers and system services are MUCH smaller than the multigigabyte images that are installed initially.  Microsoft considers WAY too much crap "Core OS"